# Latex Poster Size 70 cm X 100cm

Tags: posters, size

I need Latex Poster with size 70 cm X 100cm but there is template with size A0, A1, etc. How can I fix poster size whatever I want.

Comment: Welcome, using package `geometry` you can define any page size :-)

Comment: If `geometry` knows the `B1` format this would be `70cm x 100cm` -- and `geometry` has `b1paper` option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sciposter` package, which knows `B1` paper size (`707 mm × 1000 mm`), and `portrait/landscape` orientation.